# Python OpenCV doesn't properly return the last frame

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to get the last frame of an mp4 video using OpenCV. This code works for some videos, and doesn't for others. I believe it has something to do with the framerate of the videos, but im not quite sure. Trying to use the `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` property together with the duration of the video didn't work either. The framerate of the video is 27.75 fps.

```py
def createsample(self, videopath) -> str:
        """Gets the last frame of the video as a sample."""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)
        sample = COGSPATH + r"\data\sample.jpg"
        
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - 1) #should set last frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
            
        cv2.imwrite(sample, frame)
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return sample
```

After this code, `frame` is usually just empty and `ret` is `False`.

Comment: same old story. seeking is tricky. don't rely on it. use ffmpeg's libraries directly. OpenCV is a library for computer vision, not for handling video files.

Comment: @DeepQuantum Do you have an example video you can share where you run into this problem?